# Ejecutar .exe en PHP

Tags: php, exe

Tengo una aplicación la cual debe ejecutar un **.exe** que inicia la ejecución de un **scanner**. El ejecutable lo tengo en la unidad C pero no encuentro alguna manera de poder ejecutarlo.

Comment: Checa [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día chicos y chicas, lo solucione creando un HTML protocol desde el regedit 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Simplemente paso la ruta del ejecutable y arreglado!.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varias alternativas:

- [exec("c:\abc.exe", $resultado);](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php)

  Y entonces con un `var_dump($resultado);` podrás ver el resultado de tu programa, un elemento del array por línea enviada a stdout.
- [passthru("c:\abc.exe", $out);](http://php.net/manual/es/function.passthru.php)

  Aquí la función regresa el código de salida del programa en `$out`
- [Usando pipes y proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.proc-open.php)

  Muchas veces el output de la línea de comandos no es tan "fiable" como uno quisiera, si no te regresa el output correctamente es posible que debas considerar usar pipes para capturar todo, esto es un poco más complicado.

  `$proceso = proc_open('cmd', [["pipe", "r"], ["pipe", "w"], ["pipe", "w"]], $pipes); //abrimos el proceso cmd.exe proceso con 3 pipes, stdin, stdout y stderr
  if (is_resource($proceso)) { //si se ha creado el proceso...
     fwrite($pipes[0], '"C:\mis archivos\ejecutable.exe"'); //enviamos comando
     fclose($pipes[0]); //cerramos el pipe stdin...
     echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); //mostramos el output del pipe stdout
     fclose($pipes[1]); //cerramos el pipe stdout
     echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]); //mostramos el output del pipe stderr
     fclose($pipes[1]); //cerramos el pipe stderr
     echo proc_close($proceso); //cerramos el proceso
  }`
- [$out = shell_exec("c:\abc.exe");](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php)

  Aquí tendrás el lo que se envía a stdout en `$out`
- [$out = system("c:\abc.exe", $codigo)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.system.php)

  Finalmente aquí tendrás lo que envía stdout en `$out` y adicionalmente el código de salida del programa en `$codigo`

Comment: detalla mejor tu respuesta. los links a posibles soluciones no parecen muy explicativos

Comment: Gracias por la observación, me parecía que la información y ejemplos de la documentación oficial de PHP eran suficientes y claros. Saludos.