# ¿Cómo se utiliza el método exec() de PHP?

Tags: php, consola

Estoy intentando de utilizar dicha función pero no logro entenderla.
Lo que necesito es que desde un archivo PHP me ejecute un programa que está en el servidor (para ser especifico el DTW).

Agradezco sus repuestas.

Comment: Considera [mi respuesta] a una pregunta anterior relacionada con la ejecución de comandos externos en PHP (http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/43329/23327)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude arreglar, faltaban permisos en el apache y una configuracion en php.ini

**php.ini**

> safe_mode= off
>
> safe_mode_exec_dir= On

**Apache**
Modificar el servicio del apache para darle permisos para permitir al servicio "*interactuar con el escritorio*", para ello hacemos click en el botón Inicio->Ejecutar y escribimos Services.msc. Abrirá el "*gestor de servicios*" de windows, damos clic con el botón derecho en el Apache y clic en propiedades; 
ahora en la ventana que se abre damos clic en "*Inicio sesión*" y marcaremos la opción "*Permitir a los servicios que interactúen con el escritorio*".

Corregí eso y se abrió bien un programa en el servidor (Bloc de notas).

Answer (score 6):

#### `exec()` es un metodo que nos permite ejecutar un comando y guardar el resultado en una variable.

> De acuerdo a la documentacion de PHP

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

**El primer argumento sera el comando que deseas ejecutar y esta funcion te retornara la salida de este comando.**

#### Como podemos comprobar esto, he aqui un ejemplo:

```
<?php

$resultado = exec("ls -ls");

print "Salida: $resultado\n"; 

?>
```

> Resultado

```
Salida: 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ivan wheel  72 Mar 10 09:30 prueba.php
```

**Este seria un ejemplo basico del uso de `exec()`, aunque podemos encontrar distintas funciones para ejecutar comandos del sistema a traves de PHP**

- system()
- shell_exec()

Estas tienen otras diferencias respecto a `exec()`, por ejemplo, con `system()` tu puedes ejecutar un comando del sistema, pero no puede guardar la salida de este en una variable.

#### Ejemplo de system()

```
<?php

system("ls -lh");

?>
```

> Resultado

```
total 8.0K
drwx------ 3 ivan wheel 102 Mar 10 07:12 com.apple.launchd.DDlLxDt
```

#### Ejemplo de shell_exec()

**De acuerdo a lo que ha escrito @amenadiel y lo que podemos encontrar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)**

```
<?php

$resultado = shell_exec("ls -ls");

print "Salida: $resultado\n"; 

?>
```

> Resultado

```
Salida: total 8
0 drwx------ 3 ivan wheel 102 Mar 10 07:12 com.apple.launchd.DDlLxDt
0 drwx------ 3 ivan wheel 102 Mar 10 07:12 com.apple.launchd.YvPfVPI
0 drwx------ 3 ivan wheel 102 Mar 10 07:12 com.apple.launchd.wjUSNVW
```

**`shell_exec()` permite realizar la ejecucion de un comando, y obtener toda la salida, a diferencia de `exec()` que solo devuelve la ultima linea.**

**Ves, a diferencia de `exec()`, en el que tuve que guardar la salida para poder imprimirla posteriormente, con `system()` el comando se puede ejecutar y obtendras el resultado de manera inmediata y con `shell_exec()` se obtiene toda la salida el comando.**

Mas informacion al respecto: [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. Entiendo, pero cómo puedo lograr ejecutar un programa desde PHP? Lo único que encontré fue la función exec() de PHP, pero veo que no es para eso.

Comment: Mira el ejemplo que he escrito

Comment: Si tienes un programa solo haces `exec("COMANDO")`

Comment: O tambien puedes usar `system("comando")`

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
estoy haciendo esto.
´exec("D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Intranet\\Cmd\\ControlAverias\\EntradaMercancia.cmd", $output);
    
      foreach ($output as $value)
      {
        echo $value . "<br>";
      }

      echo $result;´

Comment: Que error te arroja?

Comment: Si gustas podriamos pasar la conversacion al chat

Comment: No arroja nada. Y tampoco ejecuta el programa. Mejor dicho no hace nada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55126/discussion-between-ivan-botero-and-daniel-torres).

Comment: faltó añadir que shell_exec te asigna en la variable toda la salida del comando, no sólo la última línea como exec

Comment: @amenadiel Lo habia olvidado, ya lo agrego para hacer mas completo el ejemplo, gracias

Comment: ahora sí quedó de lujo