# php no ejecuta bien archivo python

Tags: php, python, pytube

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intentado llamar un archivo python desde php, el problema es que el archivo como tal si se ejecuta, lo malo es que no hace lo que se supone que debe hacer, este es mi archivo python, es muy simple, lo que hace es descargar un video de youtube con la librería pytube:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
video = YouTube(url)

video = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
video.download('dir')
```

Ahora si yo ejecuto ese archivo de esta manera en la consola (por ejemplo):

```
python3 file.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwzD8U4u76k
```

El archivo si se descarga, si reviso la carpeta donde se debe descargar el archivo si está descargado, pero ahora tengo un problema al ejecutar ese mismo comando con php, con php yo ejecuto el comando de está forma:

```
system("python3 file.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwzD8U4u76k", $exit);
```

Y al hacer eso no pasa nada, la carpeta donde se debe descargar el archivo sigue igual, y si reviso la variable `exit` me devuelve `1`, espero me puedan ayudar a resolver mi problema. Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: Te sugiero intentar con [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) para que captures la salida y puedas saber cuál es el error que, podría ser por cuestión de rutas y tengas que especificar la ruta absoluta de `file.py`.

Comment: @Triby intenté tanto con la función `exec` y escribiendo la ruta absoluta del archivo, pero sigue dandome exactamente el mismo resultado

Comment: @Triby copie el código que pusiste como respuesta, lo adapté y obtengo lo mismo, un array vació pero el "código de estado" me devuelve 1

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54474/54039) a ver si sirve de algo.

Comment: ¿has probado poniendo la ruta absoluta al comando `python3` tambien? ¿O si la función `system` esta deshabilitada en el servidor? (con phpinfo() busca **disabled_functions**)

Comment: @Triby intenté lo de la respuesta que comentaste, y obtengo exactamente el mismo resultado, lo que hice fue exactamente poner `off` en las funciones safe_mode en el php.ini

Comment: @masterguru he revisado `disabled_functions` y está vacio

Comment: Pues acabo de probar tu código en mi propio portatil y me ha funcionado, tanto en python3 como en php con el system tal cual lo tienes tu... sera alguna medida de proteccion de alli donde lo estes ejecutando... es un servidor o es tu pc?

Comment: @masterguru estoy ejecutandolo desde mi propia pc

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, revisa la respuesta actualizada, a ver si te sirve de algo.

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía ejem, bueno, que conste que antes, cuando decia que me ha funcionado, era porque lo habia probado desde consola, con `php script.php` donde ese `script.php` contiene la llamada al `system` (en tu pregunta no aclaras desde donde y me ha parecido más facil probarlo asi para empezar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy suponiendo que trabajas en una distribución Linux derivada de Debian o Ubuntu.

Al instalar `pytube` mediante `pip`, como se sugiere en el [manual](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/install.html), aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> WARNING: The script pytube is installed in '/home/USUARIO/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
> Successfully installed pytube-11.0.2

La librería queda solo disponible para el usuario con el que la instalaste y no vas a poder acceder a ella ejecutando bajo el usuario de Apache, generalmente `www-data`. Supongo que la librería no se puede importar en Python y aborta la ejecución.

Podrías tratar de cambiar permisos, de carpetas, usuario de Apache, etc., pero lo ideal sería no meterte en esas configuraciones y tratar de que esté disponible para todos los usuarios. Desconozco si se puede hacer descargando desde Github y compilando; será cuestión de probar.

Si no se puede, entonces la opción *"más fácil"* sería cambiar el usuario de Apache y los permisos de la carpeta correspondiente.

Desde la terminal ejecuta:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Busca las dos siguientes líneas y remplaza `www-data` con tu usuario (la primera) y tu grupo de usuarios (la segunda):

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

**Nota:** En la instalación de Ubuntu, generalmente se crea un grupo con el mismo nombre de usuario; en mi caso, tanto el usuario como el grupo son `triby`.

Presiona <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> para guardar los cambios y <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> para salir del editor.

Sin salir de la terminal, cambia los permisos de la carpeta donde tienes tu proyecto; suponiendo que es la ruta por defecto:

```
sudo chown -R USUARIO:GRUPO /var/www/html
```

La opción `-R` es para aplicar los permisos también a todo el contenido de la carpeta y no olvides remplazar `USUARIO` y `GRUPO` por los que corresponden a tu usuario.

Finalmente, reinicia Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Con eso ya debes tener resuelto el problema de permisos y tu script debería funcionar.

Con [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) puedes capturar la salida para saber lo que está pasando. Seguramente deberás especificar la ruta completa del script, porque `exec()` podría ser ejecutado desde otra ubicación:

```
// Declarar variables, porque se pasan por referencia
$salida = [];
$resultado = 0;
// Ajusta la ruta del script
exec("python3 /var/www/html/file.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwzD8U4u76k", $salida, $resultado);
// Ver qué está pasando
var_dump($salida, $resultado);
```

De acuerdo al manual, en el segundo parámetro obtendrás la salida del comando:

> Si el argumento output está presente, entonces el array especificado será llenado con cada línea de la salida del comando. El espacio en blanco extra, como \n, no es incluido en este array.

Si hay un error, ahí lo debes ver.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, perdón apenas ahorita pude probar lo que dijiste, y ya al hacerlo ya funcionó todo bien, muchas gracias :).