# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script de python vía php?

Tags: php, python

El caso es que me gustaría ejecutar un script vía php utilizando el método exec.

Con ejemplos sencillos de prueba en los que se hace un print en el .py, la cosa funciona perfectamente.

Sin embargo, cuando intento amoldar un .py que tiene importación de módulos, no lo ejecuta.

¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ser?

Comment: Por favor aporta un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola buenos días puedes colocar el código que tienes y si te estas generando algún error por favor colócalo.

Comment: Tu problema puede ser que  tu servidor no tiene instalados los modulos necesarios para correr tu script, podrías intentar instalarlos con pip, pero lo mas seguro es que tu servidor no te de los permisos para instalarlos.

Comment: Usa pipes - https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43327/ejecutar-exe-en-php/43329#43329