# Hay forma de saber si un exe se está ejecutando desde php o js?

Tags: php, javascript, c#, exe, ejecutar

Pues me encuentro con que en el equipo que uso como webserver para una aplicación local, además del webserver hay un par de ficheros exe que realizan labores de limpieza de archivos antiguos. 
Estos archivos exe, de vez en cuando y por problemas de conectividad de las unidades de red que monitorizan, causan algún tipo de excepción y se bloquean, dejando de realizar sus tareas.

Me gustaría saber si, dado que es el mismo equipo que el webserver, puedo realizar algún fichero php que se autorefresque cada X minutos y compruebe si el archivo exe de turno está en ejecución en el mismo ordenador, y de no estarlo lo puedo ejecutar desde el mismo php con cualquiera de [estas funciones php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43327/ejecutar-exe-en-php)

Hay que comentar que el archivo exe está hecho con c# y tengo acceso al código, aunque de c# estoy muy pez la verdad y como no es mi código preferiría no meterle mano aunque... se me ocurre que quizá con un try/catch se podría solucionar, pero vamos, que prefiero hacerlo desde php/js si es posible.

Comment: Con el comando tasklist de windows si es el sistema operativo de tu servidor puedes ver los programas que se esten ejecutando, lo ejecutas desde php y obtienes la salida como string, buscas el que ejecutastes y si no aparece haces lo que querias. Otra opcion es hacer una app en c# de consola que te devuelva si existe o no una aplicación dada, y en este caso en vez de ejecutar tasklist ejecutarias esta app.

Comment: Me gusta tu idea del tasklist, no conocía ese comando para windows. Afortunadamente el webserver está sobre un win7, así que voy a probar a lanzarlo.

Comment: Dariel me ha funcionado estupendamente bien tu tasklist :)
Si te parece bien, ponlo como respuesta para que que la pueda marcar como respuesta confirmada para otros usuarios.

Comment: Ya lo puse y te ejemplifique una mejor manera de resolver tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el comando tasklist de windows si es el sistema operativo de tu servidor puedes ver los programas que se esten ejecutando, lo ejecutas desde php y obtienes la salida como string, buscas el que ejecutastes y si no aparece haces lo que querias. Estuve indagando un poco mas y aki te dejo mi respuesta, sigo usando tasklist pero puedo acotar la busqueda pasandole un filtro el código esta documentado.

```
<?php
//Función para verificar si existe o no una aplicacion esta corriendo
/**
* @param string $name Nombre del proceso que se verificara puede contener la extencón o no
*/
function verify_run_app($name){
    //Asigno a esta variable el nombre completo del proceso en caso de que no hayan pasado el $name con el .exe
    $full_name = (strpos(strtolower($name), '.exe') !== false) ? $name : $name.'.exe';
    //Listo las tareas en ejecución con el filtro donde el nombre de la imagen coincida con el nombre completo
    $proc = @popen('tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq '.$full_name.'"',"r");
    //Inicializo la variable que contendra la salida de la ejecución de el proceso tasklist
    $content = '';
    //While no llegue al fin del archivo voy almacenando la salida del proceso
    while(!feof($proc)){
        $content .= fread($proc,1024);  
    }
    //Cierro el pipe
    pclose($proc);
    //Devuelvo true si el texto que devolvio no contiene el texto 'no hay tareas'
    return (strpos($content, 'no hay tareas') === false);
}

$esta_corriendo = verify_run_app("navicat");
if($esta_corriendo){
    echo "SI EXISTE LA APLICACION CORRIENDO";
} else {
    echo "LA APLICACION NO ESTA CORRIENDO";
}
```

Comment: ex ce len te :)

Comment: jajaj Gracias espero ke les sirva a muchos +

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq BasculaPlus.exe" | find "BasculaPlus.exe" > NUL
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
  echo Servicio Ya Activo

) ELSE (
  start C:\BasculaPlusProductivo\BasculaPlus.exe
  exit
)
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte

Comment: Siempre será útil para quien pregunta y para quienes tengan el mismo problema en el futuro, explicar cómo se debería usar cuaquier fragmento de código que sugerimos. Considera editar tu respuesta y dar una breve explicación.